# The PIL show() method looks for the default viewer. How do I change this to a different viewer (of my choice)?

Tags: python, display

I am using the Python Imaging Library (PIL), Python 2 and Raspberry Pi 3 B+

My code is simply:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(‘somepic.jpg’)
im.show() # display image
```

But the show() method looks for the default viewer (probably xv). How do I change this (in the code, or in some settings) to a different viewer (of my choice)?

Comment: The Pi is irrelevant to any answer you may find.  Perhaps search without using the Pi as a search term.

Comment: Pi might be relevant. For example, there could be a setting to change the default viewer.